# How to enable kvm/qemu logs?

Tags: qemu, kvm

I'm working in company where by they are using kvm virtualisation

```
[root@601 log]# virsh list --all --title
 Id    Name                           State      Title
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2     reporting-pilosa07             running    10.3.6.172
 3     reporting-pilosa09             running    10.3.6.173
 4     reporting-pilosa11             running    10.3.6.174
 5     reporting-pilosa13             running    10.3.6.175
 6     reporting-pilosa05             running    10.3.6.171
```

the VMs are running, but time to time, they dead for some reason and I would like to look at individual VM logs

```
[root@601 qemu]# ls -ltr
total 32
-rw------- 1 root root 2341 Oct 15  2018 reporting-pilosa07.log
-rw------- 1 root root 2341 Oct 15  2018 reporting-pilosa09.log
-rw------- 1 root root 2341 Oct 15  2018 reporting-pilosa11.log
-rw------- 1 root root 2341 Oct 15  2018 reporting-pilosa13.log
-rw------- 1 root root 4885 Nov 12  2018 reporting-pilosa05.log
-rw------- 1 root root 7181 Jul 25 04:14 offlineonboarder02.log
[root@601 qemu]# pwd
/var/log/libvirt/qemu
```

The logs are not logging since a year back. Where can I enable back the logs so that I can observe the cause to why the VMs went dead?

Thanks.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237409/logging-and-debugging-for-qemu-virtual-machines